# Pulseaudio 4 : error while loading shared libraries libpulsecore-4.0.so

Tags: raspbian, audio

I'm using Raspbian, which runs Pulseaudio 2, which consume a high volume of ressources when working with my Debian sid Pulseaudio 4.

So I try to compile Pulseaudio 4 (official archive) on my raspberry.

The process went well : configure, make and install.

But Pulseaudio won't start, I get a

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecore-4.0.so
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Pulseaudio 2 **was not** installed on the system.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you get to this point after following [LFS Pulseaudio](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/pulseaudio.html)? This doesn't work on debian. I think I finally got this working by actually replacing default pulseaudio folders.

Answer (score 1):

Does the file `libpulsecore-4.0.so` exist on your system (`locate` might not know about it even if it's there, try `find` instead), if so where is it? If it's in one of the lib folders then running `sudo ldconfig` may help.

If it isn't in one of the normal lib locations, then you can try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the folder that it is before running your program.

If the file doesn't exist at all then you've almost certainly got a build problem somewhere. You may find it easier to try `dpkg` and build from the source package instead as that will have the correct configuration already set up for you.